# Dynamically constructing filters in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am looking for a way to dynamically construct filters using SQLAlchemy. That is, given the column, the operator name and the comparing value, construct the corresponding filter.

I'll try to illustrate using an example (this would be used to build an API). Let's say we have the following model:

```
class Cat(Model):

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)
  age = Column(Integer)
```

I would like to map queries to filters. For example,

- `/cats?filter=age;eq;3` should generate `Cat.query.filter(Cat.age == 3)`
- `/cats?filter=age;in;5,6,7&filter=id;ge;10` should generate `Cat.query.filter(Cat.age.in_([5, 6, 7])).filter(Cat.id >= 10)`

I looked around to see how it has been done but couldn't find a way that didn't involve manually mapping each operator name to a comparator or something similar. For instance, [Flask-Restless](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) keeps a dictionary of all supported operations and stores the corresponding lambda functions ([code here](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/blob/master/flask_restless/search.py)).

I searched in the SQLAlchemy docs and found two potential leads but neither seemed satisfying:

- using `Column.like`, `Column.in_`...: these operators are available directly on the column  which would make it simple using `getattr` but some are still missing (`==`, `>`, etc.).
- using `Column.op`: e.g. `Cat.name.op('=')('Hobbes')` but this doesn't seem to work for all operators (`in` namely).

Is there a clean way to do this without `lambda` functions?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In case this is useful to someone, here is what I ended up doing:

```
from flask import request

class Parser(object):

  sep = ';'

  # ...

  def filter_query(self, query):
    model_class = self._get_model_class(query) # returns the query's Model
    raw_filters = request.args.getlist('filter')
    for raw in raw_filters:
      try:
        key, op, value = raw.split(self.sep, 3)
      except ValueError:
        raise APIError(400, 'Invalid filter: %s' % raw)
      column = getattr(model_class, key, None)
      if not column:
        raise APIError(400, 'Invalid filter column: %s' % key)
      if op == 'in':
        filt = column.in_(value.split(','))
      else:
        try:
          attr = filter(
            lambda e: hasattr(column, e % op),
            ['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']
          )[0] % op
        except IndexError:
          raise APIError(400, 'Invalid filter operator: %s' % op)
        if value == 'null':
          value = None
        filt = getattr(column, attr)(value)
      query = query.filter(filt)
    return query
```

This covers all SQLAlchemy column comparators:

- `eq` for `==`
- `lt` for `<`
- `ge` for `>=`
- `in` for `in_`
- `like` for `like`
- etc.

The exhaustive list with their corresponding names can be found [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty.Comparator).

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Adapted this snippet and it works wonderfully.

Comment: Sweet! This is exactly what I have been fighting with how to do.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit on how that lambda works? It's wrapped inside a filter function now, but referencing a string expander outside of the filter function. Will this cause potential problems?

Comment: @mtth: Can you please explain the following code snippet: `attr = filter(
            lambda e: hasattr(column, e % op),
            ['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']
          )[0] % op` part, in details?

Comment: In python 3 change line to `attr = list(filter(lambda e: hasattr(column, e % op_name),['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']))[0] % op_name` else you get `TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Alternatively, in 3.6+: `attr = next((op for op in (op_name, f'{op_name}_', f'__{op_name}__') if hasattr(column, op)), None)` (and check for None to throw the API error, or remove the default and catch the `StopIteration` exception).

Comment: @Arjan can you explain what the code you provided is doing?

Comment: @Kurian, the `(op_name, f'{op_name}_', f'__{op_name}__')` uses f-strings to create a tuple of 3 possible method names, given `op_name`. So, for `eq` that yields `('eq', 'eq_', '__eq__')`. With that tuple, `(op for op in (...) if hasattr(column, op))` is a conditional generator expression, yielding an iterator with only the name(s) of the method(s) that actually exist in `column`. So, typically that leaves only, say, `'__eq__'` for `'eq'`, or only `'in_'` for `'in'`. Finally, `next(..., None)` gets the first item of the iterator, or `None` if the iterator has no items. Does that help?

Answer (score 24):

One useful trick while building multiple expression filter:

```
filter_group = list(Column.in_('a','b'),Column.like('%a'))
query = query.filter(and_(*filter_group))
```

Using this approach will allow you to combine expressions with and/or logic.
Also this will allow you to avoid recursion calls like in your answer.

Comment: This would be useful for `or_` but AFAIK there is no difference between chaining filters and using `and_`.  Where do you see any recursive calls?

Comment: My bad. I misinterpreted ``query = query.filter(filt)`` as recursive call to ``filter_query``

Comment: No worries - thanks for the suggestion, it might come in handy if decide to implement more complex filters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[sqlalchemy-elasticquery](https://github.com/loverajoel/sqlalchemy-elasticquery)** for construct dynamically filters using SQLAlchemy.

```
?filters={ "age" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

improving https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876320/12562701, you can get more complex filters

Dict to map op

```
dict_filtros_op = {
    '==':'eq',
    '!=':'ne',
    '>':'gt',
    '<':'lt',
    '>=':'ge',
    '<=':'le',
    'like':'like',
    'ilike':'ilike',
    'in':'in'
}
```

Class dao:

```
class BaseDao():
    @classmethod
    @init_db_connection
    def create_query_select(cls, model, filters=None, columns=None):
        return cls.db_session.query(*cls.create_query_columns(model=model, columns=columns))\
            .filter(*cls.create_query_filter(model=model, filters=filters))

    @classmethod
    def create_query_filter(cls, model, filters):
        '''
        return sqlalchemy filter list
        Args:
            model:sqlalchemy  model (classe das tabelas)
            filters: filter dict
                     ex:
                        filters = {
                            'or_1':{
                                'and_1':[('id', '>', 5),('id', '!=', 3)],
                                'and_2':[('fase', '==', 'arquivado')]
                            },
                            'and':[('test', '==', 'test')]
                        }
        Returns:
            filt: sqlalchemy filter list
         '''
        if not filters:
            return []

        filt = []
        for condition in filters:
            if type(filters[condition]) == dict:
                if 'and' in condition:
                    filt.append(and_(*cls.create_query_filter(model, filters[condition])))
                elif 'or' in condition:
                    filt.append(or_(*cls.create_query_filter(model, filters[condition])))
                else:
                    raise Exception('Invalid filter condition: %s' % condition)
                continue
            filt_aux = []
            for t_filter in filters[condition]:
                try:
                    column_name, op, value = t_filter
                except ValueError:
                    raise Exception('Invalid filter: %s' % t_filter)
                if not op in dict_filtros_op:
                    raise Exception('Invalid filter operation: %s' % op)
                column = getattr(model, column_name, None)
                if not column:
                    raise Exception('Invalid filter column: %s' % column_name)
                if dict_filtros_op[op] == 'in':
                    filt.append(column.in_(value))
                else:
                    try:
                        attr = list(filter(lambda e: hasattr(column, e % dict_filtros_op[op]), ['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']))[0] % dict_filtros_op[op]
                    except IndexError:
                        raise Exception('Invalid filter operator: %s' % dict_filtros_op[op])
                    if value == 'null':
                        value = None
                    filt_aux.append(getattr(column, attr)(value))
            if 'and' in condition:
                filt.append(and_(*filt_aux))
            elif 'or' in condition:
                filt.append(or_(*filt_aux))
            else:
                raise Exception('Invalid filter condition: %s' % condition)
        return filt

    @classmethod
    def create_query_columns(cls, model, columns):
        '''
        Return a list of attributes (columns) from the class model
        Args:
            model: sqlalchemy model
            columns: string list
                     ex: ['id', 'cnj']
        Returns:
            cols: list of attributes from the class model
         '''
        if not columns:
            return [model]

        cols = []
        for column in columns:
            attr = getattr(model, column, None)
            if not attr:
                raise Exception('Invalid column name %s' % column)
            cols.append(attr)
        return cols
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Place(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    search_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('search.id'), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def dinamic_filter(model_class, filter_condition):
        '''
        Return filtered queryset based on condition.
        :param query: takes query
        :param filter_condition: Its a list, ie: [(key,operator,value)]
        operator list:
            eq for ==
            lt for <
            ge for >=
            in for in_
            like for like
            value could be list or a string
        :return: queryset
        '''
        __query = db.session.query(model_class)
        for raw in filter_condition:
            try:
                key, op, value = raw
            except ValueError:
                raise Exception('Invalid filter: %s' % raw)
            column = getattr(model_class, key, None)
            if not column:
                raise Exception('Invalid filter column: %s' % key)
            if op == 'in':
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    filt = column.in_(value)
                else:
                    filt = column.in_(value.split(','))
            else:
                try:
                    attr = list(filter(lambda e: hasattr(column, e % op), ['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']))[0] % op
                except IndexError:
                    raise Exception('Invalid filter operator: %s' % op)
                if value == 'null':
                    value = None
                filt = getattr(column, attr)(value)
            __query = __query.filter(filt)
        return __query
```

Execute like:

```
places = Place.dinamic_filter([('search_id', 'eq', 1)]).all()
```