# Can I dynamically change order_by attributes in my query call?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have the following query call:

```
SearchList = (DBSession.query(
    func.count(ExtendedCDR.uniqueid).label("CallCount"),
    func.sum(ExtendedCDR.duration).label("TotalSeconds"),
    ExtendedCDR,ExtensionMap)
    .filter(or_(ExtensionMap.exten == ExtendedCDR.extension,ExtensionMap.prev_exten == ExtendedCDR.extension))
    .filter(between(ExtendedCDR.start,datebegin,dateend))
    .filter(ExtendedCDR.extension.in_(SelectedExtension))
    .group_by(ExtendedCDR.extension)
    .order_by(func.count(ExtendedCDR.uniqueid).desc()))
    .all()
)
```

I would like to be able to define the order_by clause prior to calling the .query(), is this possible?

I tried doing as [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887813/940839) suggests for a filter spec, but I had no idea how to create the filter_group syntax.

From that post:

```
filter_group = list(Column.in_('a','b'),Column.like('%a'))
query = query.filter(and_(*filter_group))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You build a SQL query with the `DBSession.query()` call, and this query is not executed until you call `.all()` on it.

You can store the intermediary results and add more filters or other clauses as needed:

```
search =DBSession.query(
    func.count(ExtendedCDR.uniqueid).label("CallCount"),
    func.sum(ExtendedCDR.duration).label("TotalSeconds"),
    ExtendedCDR,ExtensionMap)
search = search.filter(or_(
    ExtensionMap.exten == ExtendedCDR.extension,
    ExtensionMap.prev_exten == ExtendedCDR.extension))
search = search.filter(between(ExtendedCDR.start, datebegin, dateend))
search = search.filter(ExtendedCDR.extension.in_(SelectedExtension))
search = search.group_by(ExtendedCDR.extension)
search = search.order_by(func.count(ExtendedCDR.uniqueid).desc())
```

The value you pass to `order_by` can be created ahead of time:

```
search_order = func.count(ExtendedCDR.uniqueid).desc()
```

then used like:

```
search = search.order_by(search_order)
```

Once your query is complete, get the results by calling `.all()`:

```
SearchList = search.all()
```