# Build sqlalchemy query from string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, blaze

How can I convert a sql where clause string to a sqlalchemy query? I'm assuming I already know the table.

I'm building an Angular webapp which hits a Flask API for data.  Flask is using sqlalchemy to query the db. jQuery-QueryBuilder fromSQL  (http://querybuilder.js.org/plugins.html#import-export) exports filters as raw SQL which I want to pass back to the api, parse, and query.

For example:

```
where_str = "name LIKE '%BOB%' AND fruit != 'pineapple'"
```

would get converted to:

```
session.query(Table).filter(Table.name.like('%BOB%')).filter(Table.fruit != 'pineapple)
```

Tagging blaze because odo might be what I need.

Comment: Check this Thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845196/dynamically-constructing-filters-in-sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845196/dynamically-constructing-filters-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to execute `session.query(Table).filter(where_str)`. It worked for me on SQLAlchemy v0.5.8.
You can also build the whole SQL statement string and use the [Connection.execute()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) method to execute it. Either way, passing SQL statements as strings directly from the webpage to the application [can be very dangerous](https://m1el.github.io/printf-antipattern/).

Comment: Yea I know you can do execute but you need a full SQL statement.  I only have the WHERE part of the statement.

Comment: Which version of SQLAlchemy are you using? Our application still runs a very old one (0.5.8), but Ive tried something like `session.query(Table).filter(where_str)` and it worked

Comment: I'm using 1.0.6, and you're right.  Though it will work, it gives warnings for using a string directly and suggests using http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text such as `session.query(Table).filter(text(where_str))`.  To reiterate what Matheus said, its not very safe to let your api accept a SQL string but that's a separate topic.

Comment: This is super powerful once you understand what it means.  Sometimes it is harder to write the filter portion in SqlAlchemy than it is to just write it out in SQL (especially when user input is NOT involved).  Knowing this is possible is gonna save me a lot of time.

Comment: In my case, I am building an API that returns a result set from SQLAlchemy, and I want the API client to be able to filter the result set with a string, so being able to just pass a string to "filter" or sanitize the string and pass that in would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to filter twice to add an AND you can do this:

```
session.query(Table).filter(Table.name.like('%BOB%'), Table.fruit != 'pineapple)
```

Comment: yeah sorry, no the answer but might be helpful in the future :)