# sqlalchemy dynamic filtering

Tags: python, dynamic, sqlalchemy, filtering

I'm trying to implement dynamic filtering using SQLAlchemy ORM.

I was looking through StackOverflow and found very similar question:[SQLALchemy dynamic filter_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885879/sqlalchemy-dynamic-filter-by)

It's useful for me, but not enough.

So, here is some example of code, I'm trying to write:

```
# engine - MySQL engine
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session_maker()

# my custom model
model = User

def get_query(session, filters):
    if type(filters) == tuple:
        query = session.query(model).filter(*filters)
    elif type(filters) == dict:
        query = session.query(model).filter(**filters)
    return query
```

then I'm trying to reuse it with something very similar:

```
filters = (User.name == 'Johny')
get_query(s, filters) # it works just fine

filters = {'name': 'Johny'}
get_query(s, filters)
```

After the second run, there are some issues:

```
TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

When I'm trying to change my `filters` to:

```
filters = {User.name: 'Johny'}
```

it returns:

```
TypeError: filter() keywords must be strings
```

But it works fine for manual querying:

```
s.query(User).filter(User.name == 'Johny')
```

What is wrong with my filters?

BTW, it looks like it works fine for case:

```
filters = {'name':'Johny'}
s.query(User).filter_by(**filters)
```

But following the recommendations from mentioned post I'm trying to use just `filter`.

If it's just one possible to use `filter_by` instead of `filter`, is there any differences between these two methods?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your problem is that filter_by takes keyword arguments, but filter takes expressions. So expanding a dict for filter_by **mydict will work. With filter, you normally pass it one argument, which happens to be an expression. So when you expand your **filters dict to filter, you pass filter a bunch of keyword arguments that it doesn't understand.

If you want to build up a set of filters from a dict of stored filter args, you can use the generative nature of the query to keep applying filters. For example:

```
# assuming a model class, User, with attributes, name_last, name_first
my_filters = {'name_last':'Duncan', 'name_first':'Iain'}
query = session.query(User)
for attr,value in my_filters.iteritems():
    query = query.filter( getattr(User,attr)==value )
# now we can run the query
results = query.all()
```

The great thing about the above pattern is you can use it across multiple joined columns, you can construct 'ands' and 'ors' with and_ and or_, you can do <= or date comparisons, whatever. It's much more flexible than using filter_by with keywords. The only caveat is that for joins you have to be a bit careful you don't accidentally try to join a table twice, and you might have to specify the join condition for complex filtering. I use this in some very complex filtering over a pretty involved domain model and it works like a charm, I just keep a dict going of entities_joined to keep track of the joins.

Comment: It's the answer for my question. I'm not sure if I'll use it instead of filter_by, but it was interesting how to use filter for my case. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. Do you have any examples or code you can link where you use this for complex filtering? In particular, I'm trying to generate queries for `and` / `or` operations dynamically based on an input query syntax. e.g. "last_name:duncan or first_name:Iain"

Comment: @JacobPavlock,

You can use [sqlalchemy-filters](https://github.com/juliotrigo/sqlalchemy-filters), or their copy their api design.

Answer (score 6):

I have a similar issue, tried to filter from a dictionary:

```
filters = {"field": "value"}
```

Wrong:

```
...query(MyModel).filter(**filters).all()
```

Good:

```
...query(MyModel).filter_by(**filters).all()
```

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, There's a Python library designed to solve this exact problem: [sqlalchemy-filters](https://github.com/juliotrigo/sqlalchemy-filters)

It allows to dynamically filter using all operators, not only `==`.

```py
from sqlalchemy_filters import apply_filters


# `query` should be a SQLAlchemy query object

filter_spec = [{'field': 'name', 'op': '==', 'value': 'name_1'}]
filtered_query = apply_filters(query, filter_spec)

more_filters = [{'field': 'foo_id', 'op': 'is_not_null'}]
filtered_query = apply_filters(filtered_query, more_filters)

result = filtered_query.all()
```

Comment: Warning to all: the `sqlalchemy_filters` repository has been abandoned by the creator and they won't merge a PR to make it compatible with SQL Alchemy 1.4. If you're using 1.4 or beyond this package won't work.

Answer (score 1):

For flask python 3.9, you can try

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
class DbDynamicFilter:
   def __init__(self, table):
    self.table = table
    print("DynamicJsonFilter", table)

   def json_filter(self, my_filters):
    try:
        print(self.table, my_filters)
        query = db.session.query(self.table)
        for attr, value in my_filters.items():
            if hasattr(self.table, attr):
                query = query.filter(getattr(self.table, attr) == value)
        # now we can run the query
        return query
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

And then you can user:

```
hotels_query = DbDynamicFilter(BookingHotels).json_filter(args_dict)
if hotels_query:
   print(hotels_query.all()) #for all
   print(hotels_query.first()) # for first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Place(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    search_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('search.id'), nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def dynamic_filter(model_class, filter_condition):
        '''
        Return filtered queryset based on condition.
        :param query: takes query
        :param filter_condition: Its a list, ie: [(key,operator,value)]
        operator list:
            eq for ==
            lt for <
            ge for >=
            in for in_
            like for like
            value could be list or a string
        :return: queryset
        '''
        __query = db.session.query(model_class)
        for raw in filter_condition:
            try:
                key, op, value = raw
            except ValueError:
                raise Exception('Invalid filter: %s' % raw)
            column = getattr(model_class, key, None)
            if not column:
                raise Exception('Invalid filter column: %s' % key)
            if op == 'in':
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    filt = column.in_(value)
                else:
                    filt = column.in_(value.split(','))
            else:
                try:
                    attr = list(filter(lambda e: hasattr(column, e % op), ['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']))[0] % op
                except IndexError:
                    raise Exception('Invalid filter operator: %s' % op)
                if value == 'null':
                    value = None
                filt = getattr(column, attr)(value)
            __query = __query.filter(filt)
        return __query
```

Execute like:

```
places = Place.dynamic_filter([('search_id', 'eq', 1)]).all()
```

Comment: Credit where credit is due: it seems this is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876320 ?

Comment: @Arjan not really. But this way seems to solve the same problem. Thanks for adding the link here.

Comment: Well, credit where credit is due: where did you find this then? Yeah, I know you posted this a year ago. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the people using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy, here is a example of dynamic filtering:

api/app/app/crud/order.py

```py
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import UUID4
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from app.crud.base import CRUDBase
from app.models.order import Order
from app.schemas.order import OrderCreate, OrderUpdate


class CRUDOrder(CRUDBase[Order, OrderCreate, OrderUpdate]):

    def get_orders(
        self,
        db: Session,
        owner_id: UUID4,
        status: str,
        trading_type: str,
        pair: str,
        skip: int = 0,
        limit: int = 100,
    ) -> Optional[Order]:
        filters = {
            arg: value
            for arg, value in locals().items()
            if arg != "self" and arg != "db" and arg != "skip" and arg != "limit" and value is not None
        }
        query = db.query(self.model)
        for attr, value in filters.items():
            query = query.filter(getattr(self.model, attr) == value)
        return (
            query
            .offset(skip)
            .limit(limit)
            .all()
        )


order = CRUDOrder(Order)
```