# sqlalchemy dynamic filtering with and_ and or_

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Based on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309069/4472984), i want built a dynamic filter with multiple and_ and or_ levels.
My filter conditions looks like this:

```
filters = [{Contact.shown_name: 'a', Contact.town: 'b'}, {Contact.shown_name: 'c'}]
```

The conditions in one dictionary should be in a AND-clause. The dictionarys itself should be in an OR-clause.

I want the result from this filter:

```
    .filter(or_(and_(Contact.shown_name.ilike('%a%'), Contact.town.ilike('%b%')),
                and_(Contact.shown_name.ilike('%c%'))))
```

I want to filter all items where the shown_name contains 'a' and the town contains 'b' OR all items where the shown_name contains 'c'.

The number of condition and dictionarys in the list 'filters' is flexible.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the logic using nested comprehensions and argument unpacking.

```
filters = or_(*[and_(*[c.ilike(f"%{v}%") for c, v in f.items()]) for f in filters])
```

If you prefer a more verbose approach:

```
# This assumes there's always at least one filter in the list
res = literal(False)
for f in filters:
    tmp = literal(True)
    for c, v in f.items():
        tmp &= c.ilike(f"%{v}%")

    res |= tmp

filters = res
```

Comment: is this python 3.9 syntax? ( the |= and &=) ?

Comment: Is it possible, you have forget '.items()' on iter through the dict. This code works as expected: filters = or_(*[and_(*[c.ilike(f"%{v}%") for c, v in f.items()]) for f in filters])

Comment: Yeah, forgot `items()`.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 Augmented assignment operations have been a part of Python for quite some time, at least since v2.0, if not before.

Comment: oh yeah, nevermind, the change in 3.9 was specifically about the usage with the built-in dict class