# Sqlalchemy orm dynamic query filtering from given input

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, lambda, sqlalchemy

I came across a need to create dynamic orm filtering on a given query.
I.e, given some input dictionary:
`{"orm_entitiy":"City", attribute":"id","op":">","value":"1"}`
and an existing query object `query`

Will need to evaluate to: `new_filtered_query = query.filter(City.id > 1)`

My questions are:
1. Are you familiar with some mature library which solves this need?
2. I saw a solution in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845196/dynamically-constructing-filters-in-sqlalchemy) and a [blog](http://ruddra.com/2015/09/18/dynamically-constructing-filters-based-on-string-input-using-sqlalchemy/index.html), but I have a difficulty to understand the section:

```
 attr = list(filter(
                        lambda e: hasattr(column, e % op),
                        ['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']
                    ))[0] % op
```

Could someone please describe the logic behind this in details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's uncomplicate this expression by making it more verbose.

```
existing_attrs = list(filter(<filter_func>, potential_attributes))
attr = existing_attrs[0] % op
```

The first line produces a list of objects from `potential_attributes` passing the check of `<filter_func>`.
The second line is simpler: we take the first existing attribute and apply string formatting to it.

`<filter_func>` is `lambda e: hasattr(column, e % op)`: it returns True if `column` has an attribute named `e % op`, which is a current potential_attribute with string formatting applied.

For example, if `potential_attributes` is `['%s', '%s_', '__%s__']` and `op` is `gt`, the following attributes will be checked: `column.gt`, `column.gt_` and `column.__gt__`.

Let's say we have a `column.gt_` attribute. The value that passes the check is therefore `%s_` and will be put in a list of `existing_attrs`. Then, the second line (`attr = '%s_' % 'gt'`) will produce a string `'gt_'`.

Comment: What is the meaning of `e % op`?

Comment: It's a string formatting operator. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting
Example: `"%02d" % 9` is `"09"`