# SqlAlchemy filter_by with kwargs containing lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a filter statement from `kwargs` that may contain lists as values:

```
def delete_object(self, from_table, filters, commit=True): 
    (self._session
         .query(from_table)
         .filter_by(**filters)
         .delete(synchronize_session=False))
```

The `filters` contain keys which represent columns in the table and values that are supposed to be filtered.
If the values are not lists

```
{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}
```

then it works fine. However, when the values are lists

```
{'id': [3]}
```

then the resulting sql statement that is created looks like this

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <table>.id = ARRAY[3]
```

Is there a way to handle list elements as well?

Comment: What about unpacking the list and loop? I'm not sure if SQLAlchemy has that level of robust to be able to parse your kwargs of different data objects

Comment: Yes that's an option but for lists with 100+ entries that's a lot of queries

Comment: No it wouldn't be creating individual queries for each item in the list, it would dynamically create a filter for each object in the list and then apply all the filters to a single query. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887813/6560549 for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this answer may be able to help:

[SQLAlchemy IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause)

Summing is up, you can us `_in`, like so:

```
session.query(MyUserClass)
       .filter(MyUserClass.id.in_(SOME_LIST)).all()
```

Comment: Yes I know about the `in_` but that does not really relate to my code since it takes away the dynamic part and me having to parse all kwargs manually...